# C# WinForms: activating a timer from a thread

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void timer_thing()
{
    Thread timer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
      {
          Thread.Sleep(500);
          if (is_mouse_down)
              timer1.Enabled = true;
      }
    ));
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some stuff happens here
}
```

As you can see I want the thread to activate the timer. But the timer doesn't activate. I guess this is not the right way. Or i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `is_mouse_down` is `false` whenever the thread hits that instruction. The thread is not going to magically wait for it to turn `true`.

However, you have another, bigger problem to worry about. The thing is you cannot touch any UI element from a worker thread or any other other than the UI thread. This includes the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. All sorts of undefined chaos may ensue. Your application may fail unpredictably and spectacularly.

It is not really clear to me why a thread is needed in the first place. Can you not handle the `Control.MouseDown` event and enable the timer in the event handler for that event? That is how I would solve the problem.

Comment: A Control.MouseDown event activates the thread. I tried using 2 timers (the first timer activates the second one after some time and deactivates itself). But when I use Thread.Sleep(int) in a timer, the whole program pauses. So I'm trying with a thread.

Comment: So from the `MouseDown` event activate a timer `A` that waits 500ms. Once the `Tick` event comes through from timer `A` then you can activate timer `B`.

Comment: Making a timer wait for some time before it does something... But how? I wrote that when I use Thread.Sleep(int) in a timer, the whole program pauses. And then you tell me to make the timer wait before it starts working... I am not really experienced with C#, so short answers can't always help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread isn't waiting for the `is_mouse_down` event. It just checks after half a second and if it's not the time won't get enabled and the tread closes. Maybe you should try using an event?

Comment: I tried by removing the "if (is_mouse_down)" line. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) to automatically trigger it from Button Click handler.

So in thread just set:

```
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

and in button click handler:

```
autoResetEvent.Set();
```

BTW, why you can not initialize a Timer in the Click handler?

Answer (score 0):

This problem as described in literature has two solutions:

1) Active waiting

2) Notifications

If you want the active waiting solution(which is really an outdated one, your thread should have while loop).

If you want the notification when you should call some method which starts the timer in the mouse down event handler

Answer (score 0):

If you have questions about c# multithreading you should read [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) article.  It is really helpful and will show you AutoresetEvent, ManualResetEvents, Thread Timers, Timers, etc.  Really good general article.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the timer1_Tick callback when you declare your timer object.